# Is it possible to do dips with correct form on this home workout bar?

Tags: home-exercise, calisthenics, form, dips

I have a home workout pull-up bar like the one you see on this image: https://sc04.alicdn.com/kf/Hcc0fc33b7d954a59b1e0c5a57e223431R/252614994/Hcc0fc33b7d954a59b1e0c5a57e223431R.jpg The bar is 100% stable on my door, but when I try to do dips I am afraid to lean front because my head might bump on the 2nd horizontal bar that you see counting from the top. So is it that this bar is not appropriate for dips or that my technique is wrong and I should try doing dips while keeping my upper body straight?

Comment: can you do dips facing the other way? Your back won't bump on the bars since you're not leaning back.

Comment: I don't even know why I didn't think about it before, I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the bar is designed to be hung on the door, it's unlikely that it was intended for doing dips. That aside, if it's stable enough you can definitely do dips straight up and down without leaning forward.

When you lean forward in dips, it targets a good portion of your lower chest alongside your triceps so it's good to lean forward. However, since in your case you can't lean too far forward, doing dips straight up and down is a great movement for your triceps (specifically the long head located on the back of your arm).

[image: Here's a diagram of an straight up and down dip movement]

Hopefully this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I can either do it without leaning or as @Lunciano stated in the comments I can do it facing the other way so I have nothing blocking me from leaning forward.